# View shake animation error when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I've been using the following `UIView` extension to shake a view:

```
func shake(count: Float = 4, for duration: TimeInterval = 0.5,
           withTranslation translation: CGFloat = 5) {
    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    animation.repeatCount = count
    animation.duration = duration / TimeInterval(animation.repeatCount)
    animation.autoreverses = true
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: -translation, y: self.center.y))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: translation, y: self.center.y))
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
}
```

And the usage:

```
view.shake(count: 3, for: 0.2, withTranslation: 8)
```

This works well for shaking a view (in my case I'm shaking some buttons, UIView's, and a few image views). 
The problem arises when I try clicking on one of the views during the shake animation.

I receive a:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000442640'

In the case of the buttons, if I disable the button then initiate the shake animation it seems to prevent the error from occurring. 
Unfortunately, this does not seems to work for the image views and UIViews.

I also disabled user interaction on the image views / UIView's to no avail.

I feel like this has something to do with the wrong coordinate being passed to the lower layers during a hit test check while the view is being animated.

Any insight into this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what the goal is. If the user taps a shaking view, what should happen?

Comment: @matt nothing should happen. But if the user accidentally taps on a view during an animation and it crashes my app that wouldn't be good. So to answer your question, when a user taps on a shaking view it shouldn't crash my app

Comment: Okay, so if your layer already has the shake animation, don’t add it again. — But personally I think that’s not the problem. I think the problem is that the animation itself is incorrectly constructed.

Comment: Well the hit test would not match the current visual layer position for sure. Is hit testing a must during the animation?  Add a view over it all to keep from getting touches. If it is required the hit test needs to check the presentation layer.

Comment: @agibson007 I considered overlaying a view over the problematic views but Dmitry Molokov's answer seemed to work.

Comment: @matt layer animations are automatically removed once the animation completes. If I used `isRemovedOnCompletion = false` then the animation would not have been removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this code. It should be helpful:

```
extension UIView {

    func shakeByX() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.07
        animation.repeatCount = 3
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 6, y: self.center.y))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x + 6, y: self.center.y))
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }

    func shakeByY() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.duration = 0.07
        animation.repeatCount = 3
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y - 6))
        animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y + 6))
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }
}
```

Comment: So this worked, but I'm not totally sure why. The main difference I see is that we're animating the `position` as opposed to `transform.translation.x`

Comment: @WBuck Correct, this is what I meant when I said your animation was incorrectly constructed. Your animation code itself made no sense (I'm surprised it did anything at all).

Comment: By the way you don't need the NSValue stuff; just assign the CGPoint directly to `fromValue` and `toValue`.

Comment: @matt Made no sense? The animation wasn't incorrectly constructed, I just used the wrong layer property to animate the movement.

Comment: @WBuck That's _part_ of the incoherence, but not the whole of it. If the key path were `"transform.translation.x"`, its value would be a CGFloat, not a CGPoint.